# Close banner jumps around comments after refresh

Tags: bug, comments, design, closed-questions, live-refresh

Before refresh, when page was left open the question closed:

[image]

After refresh:

[image]

Why does this swap from above comments to below? Could it be more consistent?

Comment: Sorry really can't see the difference. What jumps to where?

Comment: @ShadowWizard edited, either side of the comments.

Comment: huh, so subtle. Minor, but worth fixing!

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, I noticed because I opened a notification for the page in a new tab, and saw it change.

Comment: So when you are the last close vote the page automatically refreshes. But if you're on the page when someone else does the last close vote, what happens? Does it pop up a notification at top of question saying question is now closed, and then you click to see it and it does some ajax?

Comment: @Dronehinge nope, it just appeared for me.